# Cannot upgrade pip 9.0.1 to 9.0.3 - requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I'm trying to update `pip` using `pip install --upgrade pip`, but I get a "requirement satisfied" error and an "outdated version" message at the same time

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in 
/Users/user/Envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' 
command.
```

How do I update?

Comment: Do you by any chance have pip 9.0.3 in your global Python, but 9.0.1 in a virtualenv? That _shouldn't_ be a problem, but it seems more likely to go wrong than any other combination I can think of.

Answer (score 127):

Recently, Python.org sites [stopped supporting TLS version 1.0 and 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703), which could be causing the chicken-and-egg problem you are facing. Try upgrading `pip` *without* using `pip`:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Comment: Fails on Windows 7: `'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @StevenVascellaro perhaps just download it directly from the link above and run `python get-pip.py`? Also later versions of Python seem to be shipped with pip included

Comment: Worked for me on  Mac.

Comment: For those who want to upgrade pip3, run the same command as above but use `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: No go for me: curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

Comment: This gave me the same error: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping

Answer (score 11):

These two commands worked for me:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

then:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: No go for me: curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

Comment: Thank this solution worked best for me by paul (to split Anupam's answer into two steps) because of a permission error running the get-pip.py script after curl downloads it. Changing the last line to sudo python get-pip.py was the trick. FINALLY upgraded pip beyond 9.0.x

Answer (score 4):

Try:
Right Click Anaconda Prompt (Run as Admin)

```
>> conda update pip
```

(It worked for me)

Answer (score 2):

The curl answer above didn't work for me. This worked for me

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Yeah I got the same SSL error that inspired this.  Gaaaahhh!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in windows with Anaconda3: Add **\Anaconda3\Library\bin to windows path

```
set path=anaconda_install_path\Anaconda3\Library\bin to windows path;%path%
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue is with Anaconda. This solution worked for me: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9746#issuecomment-616314792

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information in the provided link in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.