# How do I install pip on macOS? outside of the us?

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip

I am currently outside of the US (don't know if that's the reason why these errors are coming up) 
but when I type in `sudo easy_install pip` on my terminal, I get this:

```
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found! 
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

Any help/clarification in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TLSv1 has been removed from pypi, so I don't think it's geographical. https://pyfound.blogspot.com/2017/01/time-to-upgrade-your-python-tls-v12.html has some more info, and debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip fails with SSLError on MacOS because of outdated certificate - how to recover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998942/pip-fails-with-sslerror-on-macos-because-of-outdated-certificate-how-to-recove)

Comment: Apple doesn't like GPLv3 so it ships ancient versions of many tools - `sed`, `bash`, `find`, `Python`, `PHP`, `awk` and so on. If you want to do development with Python 2.7, that's fine, but you may want to look at **homebrew** which will act as a package manager and give you up-to-date programs, including Python 3.6 and its accompanying `pip`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install Python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)